# ViewPager OOM on setting adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, out-of-memory

Crash occurs when `viewpager.setAdapter()` with log:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 22409382 byte allocation with 10594550 free bytes and 10MB until OOM
                                                       at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
                                                       at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:125)
                                                       at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:278)
                                                       at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:123)
                                                       at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flushLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:358)
                                                       at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.appendLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:303)
                                                       at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.write(FastPrintWriter.java:625)
                                                       at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.append(FastPrintWriter.java:658)
                                                       at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:691)
                                                       at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:31)
                                                       at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:324)
                                                       at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:300)
                                                       at android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(Log.java:340)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.Clog_e(RuntimeInit.java:59)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.access$200(RuntimeInit.java:43)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:85)
                                                       at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
                                                       at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

However, there is no `StringBuilder` or some other streams input and output used in my Activity or Fragment.

I tried to make the activty extends FragmentActivity but it didn't work.
The viewPager is in a `CoordinatorLayout`(I don't think crash occurs because of MD but who knows...)

Is there any one meets the same problem or knows how to fix this?

[Update]
Now I've found that oom occurs on my BaseFragment `onCreateView` `return view;`.
The view returned is a `FrameLayout` with an `ImageView`, a `TextView` and layout defined by child.

```
loadingVu.initView(LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()), container);

    vu.initView(LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()), null);
    succeedView = vu.getView();
    loadingVu.mRootView.addView(succeedView);

    onBindVu();

    View loadingVuView = loadingVu.getView();

    return loadingVuView;
```

By debugguing code I found I could get loadingVuView, but app crashed on next step.

OOM occus finally in SourceCode FragmentManager `moveToState`:

```
case Fragment.CREATED:
//...
container.addView(f.mView);
//....
```

So...Why does this happened and how to fix it?

I know how does it happens.
When I use Method `inflater.inflate(R.layout.XXX, container)` in Fragment,  it should return a FrameLayout but return ViewPager instead!!!
As u see, now the container and f.mView is the same View, then OOM occurs.
Actually it's a little problem fixed by inflate(id, container, false)...